# The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I am implementing a pipeline to analyze a repository that is in .NET,  At the moment the prepare, restore and build steps are apparently successful.

```
pipeline.yml
```

```
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_${{ replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/',''),'/','-')}}_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
    
variables:
- group: 'AWSACCOUNT'
- name: agent
  value: devops
    
trigger: none
    
resources:
  containers:
  - container: devops
    image: myimagelinuxwithsometools
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(GROUP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(GROUP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $(GROUP_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)

                        
stages:
  - stage: stage_environment_and_resource
    pool: ${{ variables.agent }}
    displayName: Create environment
    jobs:
    - job: job_build
      displayName: Build Process
      container: devops
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 1


      - task: SonarQubePrepare@5.15.0
        inputs:
          SonarQube: 'azure-sonar'
          scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
          ProjectKey: 'prynet'
          ProjectName: 'prynet'
          extraProperties: 
            sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths='$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/config/**/coverage.opencover.xml'
         
      - script: java -version
      - script: dotnet nuget --version
      - script: dotnet --version
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: "Install dotnet core"
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: "Restore dotnet packages"
        inputs:
          command: restore
          projects: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/config/SI.MX.EDGWELL.csproj"


      
      - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5.15.0 # here is the error

      - task: SonarQubePublish@5
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

but when I get to the analysis part I get this error. the other stages of build and restore seem successful.

result:

```
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8965363Z ##[section]Starting: SonarQubeAnalyze
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8971202Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8971429Z Task         : Run Code Analysis
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8971558Z Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8971744Z Version      : 5.15.0
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8971854Z Author       : sonarsource
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8972076Z Help         : Version: 5.15.0. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

[More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
2023-08-18T16:10:00.8972576Z ==============================================================================
2023-08-18T16:10:01.4549860Z [command]/usr/bin/dotnet /__w/_tasks/SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157/5.15.0/dotnet-sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end
2023-08-18T16:10:01.5469202Z SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.13
2023-08-18T16:10:01.5470595Z Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
2023-08-18T16:10:01.6265746Z Post-processing started.
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7588070Z ##[error]16:10:01.752  The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:
  1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
  2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0.25420.1 and higher are supported.
  3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
  4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7600514Z 16:10:01.752  The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7600993Z Possible causes:
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7601664Z   1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7602415Z   2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0.25420.1 and higher are supported.
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7602896Z   3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7603321Z   4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7603955Z 16:10:01.752  Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete the analysis.
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7605167Z ##[error]16:10:01.759  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7606090Z 16:10:01.759  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7704849Z ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
2023-08-18T16:10:01.7862789Z ##[section]Finishing: SonarQubeAnalyze
```

the previous step of restore : Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.46

Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions.

Finishing: Restore dotnet packages

Comment: It gives you 4 possibilities for what the problem is. Did you check into each of those possibilities?

Comment: @DanielMannI did the build for the project, but I get other errors :/